# Any command to change file names with only 4 digits after decimal point or rounded-off to nearest integer

Tags: command-line, files, batch-rename

I have a directory named "test" containing data files saved during a simulation at different times. The names of the files are like 2.01149, 2.1149, 2.35698, 2.545, 2.95874566..... **and many more** etc.

I want to have the time files with only 4 digits after the decimal point or I would like to have the file names rounded-off to a nearest integer such as 2.0115, 2.1149, 2.3670, 2.5450, 2.9588... etc. Can anyone help me how to do this?

I am new to ubuntu. May I request anyone to explain how to execute on command line, a bit clearly like where to keep directory name, etc. Thanks for understanding!!!

*Query after obtaining the solution to the above*

Hi, the command `prename -n 's/\d\.\d+/sprintf "%.4f", $&/e' *([0-9.])` helped rename my time files.

But, I am facing an error while trying to open paraview.

The terminal says: FOAM Warning :

```
From function void Foam::Time::setControls()
in file db/Time/Time.C at line 307

Reading "/Re600/2.498/uniform/time" from line 15 to line 23
Time read from time dictionary 2.497956694 differs from actual time 2.498.
This may cause unexpected database behaviour. If you are not interested in preserving time state delete the time dictionary.
```

After opening the paraview, some field values like vorticity, Lambda2 are not displayed.

How to rectify this?

Comment: If you have a new question, make a new post. Don't drastically change the post and make existing valid answers invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With perl-based `prename` and an extended glob to select the files:

```
$ prename -n 's/\d\.\d+/sprintf "%.4f", $&/e' *([0-9.])
2.01149 renamed as 2.0115
2.35698 renamed as 2.3570
2.545 renamed as 2.5450
2.95874566 renamed as 2.9587
```

(remove the `-n` once you are satisfied that it is doing the right thing).

Or - equivalently - with bash builtins and `mv`

```
$ for f in *([0-9.]); do printf -v g '%.4f' "$f"; echo mv -- "$f" "$g"; done
mv -- 2.01149 2.0115
mv -- 2.1149 2.1149
mv -- 2.35698 2.3570
mv -- 2.545 2.5450
mv -- 2.95874566 2.9587
```

(remove the `echo` to actually do it).

Comment: Hello, I am new to ubuntu. My directory name is test. It contains many files such as 2.01149, 2.35698 etc. May I request you to explain how to execute your suggestions on command line, a bit clearly.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me really, when "-n" is not used. Sorry for the earlier comment, I have done a silly mistake while using your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably other ways to do it, but Perl is the one that comes to me most easily.  To do so, go into the directory where the files are located and run the command `perl -E 'rename $_, sprintf(q(%0.4f), $_) for @ARGV' *`.

The following example demonstrates, by using `touch` to create files with the names specified in the question, runs the command to rename them, and then uses `ls` to show that they have been renamed as specified:

```
$ touch 2.01149, 2.1149 2.35698 2.545 2.95874566
$ perl -E 'rename $_, sprintf(q(%0.4f), $_) for @ARGV' *
$ ls
2.0115  2.1149  2.3570  2.5450  2.9587
```

Comment: Hello, I am new to ubuntu. My directory name is test. It contains many files such as 2.01149, 2.35698 etc. May I request you to explain how to execute your suggestions on command line, a bit clearly.

Comment: Hi, I could work out the way you have suggested. But, I have so many files. How to select all of them as mentioned in the first line $ touch 2.01149, 2.1149 2.35698 2.545 2.95874566

Comment: @vidyadhar - Edited to explain more clearly. You don't need to run the `touch` line, that was just to create dummy files to demonstrate with; sorry that was unclear. The `perl -E...` command is the only one you actually need to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Perl `rename` executable, this will do it:

```
rename -n 's/(\d+\.\d{4})\d*/$1/' *
```

Remove the `-n` once you have verified it does what you want.

Note this only *truncates* the filenames. If you want rounding up, more work would be needed.

Comment: Hello, I am new to ubuntu. My directory name is test. It contains many files such as 2.01149, 2.35698 etc. May I request you to explain how to execute your suggestions on command line, a bit clearly.

Comment: Same answer as Sergiy gave. `cd test` then copy and paste exactly the command I gave.

Comment: In console windows, you may need `Ctrl-Shift-V` to paste - or use menus.

Answer (score 0):

#### find + while + printf

```
bash-4.3$ find -type f -name "[1-9].[1-9]*" -printf "%P\0" | while IFS= read -r -d '' file;  do      echo "$file"  "$(printf "%.4f" "$file")"; done
2.1149 2.1149
2.35698 2.3570
2.545 2.5450
2.95874566 2.9587
```

Replace `echo` with `mv` for actual renaming

---

#### bash for loop and printf`:

```
bash-4.3$ for f in *;do new=$(printf "%.4f" "$f"); echo "$f" "->" "$new"; done
2.01149 -> 2.0115
2.1149 -> 2.1149
2.35698 -> 2.3570
2.545 -> 2.5450
2.95874566 -> 2.9587
```

Replace echo with `mv` and remove `"->"` part for actual replacement.

---

#### Python

```
bash-4.3$ ls
2.01149  2.1149  2.35698  2.545  2.95874566
bash-4.3$ python -c 'import sys,os;f=map(lambda x: (x,"%.4f" % float(x)),sys.argv[1:]);[os.rename(i[0],i[1]) for i in f]' *
bash-4.3$ ls
2.0115  2.1149  2.3570  2.5450  2.9587
```

Comment: Hello, I am new to ubuntu. My directory name is test. It contains many files such as 2.01149, 2.35698 etc. May I request you to explain how to execute your suggestions on command line, a bit clearly.

Comment: @vidyadhar  simply `cd` to directory and type the commands.  There's really nothing more to do